# sed: capture group not expanding

Tags: regex, sed

Can someone explain to me why my sed command isn't working?  I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.  Here's small text file that demonstrates my issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class A:
    def candy(self):
        print "cane"
```

Put that in a file and call it `test.py`

My goal is to add `@profile` before the def line with the same indentation as the function declaration.  I try with this:

```
$ sed -i '/\(  *\)def /i \
\1@profile' test.py
```

Note that the capture group should be the set of spaces before the def and I'm referencing the group with \1.

Here's my result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class A:
1@profile
    def candy(self):
        print "cane"
```

Why is that `1` being placed in there literally instead of being replaced by my capture group (four spaces)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that :

```
sed -i -e  's/^\(.*\)\(def.*\)/\1@profile\n\2/' test.py
```

Comment: Closer, but \1 needs to be in front of the \2

Comment: Is not your desired output that ? 
#!/usr/bin/env python

class A:
    @profile
def candy(self):
        print "cane"

Comment: Thus, this works:
    sed -i -e  's/^\(.*\)\(def.*\)/\1@profile\n\1\2/' test.py

Comment: You don't need to list all the capture groups, just use `&` to represent the whole RE: `sed -i -e 's/^(.*)(def.*)/\1@profile\n&/'`. Note that this wont work with some seds due to non-portable use of `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know this to be true but I'm going to assume that sed doesn't maintain captures from address selectors and into manually inserted text and in fact may not be evaluating references inside "literal" text at all.

Try `sed -e 's/\( *\)def /\1@profile\n&/' test.py` instead.

Comment: Actually, this is dropping def from function signature.

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk '{orig=$0} sub(/def.*/,"@profile"); {print orig}' file
#!/usr/bin/env python

class A:
    @profile
    def candy(self):
        print "cane"
```

simple, portable, easily extendable, debuggable, etc., etc....